# Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Object> to List<Socket>

Tags: java, android, sockets

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.ServerSocket;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;
public class MyServer {
    //定义保存所有Socket的ArrayList,并将其包装为线程安全
    public static List<Socket> socketList = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<>());
    public static void main(String[] args)throws IOException{
        ServerSocket ss=new ServerSocket(3000);
        while(true){
            Socket s=ss.accept();
            socketList.add(s);
            new Thread(new ServerThread(s)).start();
        }
    }
}
```

Why I run the program,the Console shows that"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    at com.eyck.inet.MyServer.main(MyServer.java:14)"
the error seems in line 9.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error casting Object\[\] to ContentValues\[\]](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38798196/error-casting-object-to-contentvalues)

Answer (score 0):

after modifying the line 9 to

```
    public static List<Socket> socketList
       =Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Socket>());
```

can solve the question.